# Fill in the dashes Part 5 of 10

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, movies

This is part of the Fill in the Dashes series of puzzles.

Example : F_ in the B_ ⇒ Fill in the Blanks

Some of the words will be Juxtaposed as in

e.g. : C_ K_ S_ ⇒ Clark Kent Superman or Superman Clark Kent

There is a Letter Missing in each of the following clues [and hence a word :-)].

---

D_ T_

C_ F_ N_ T_

N_ W_

A A_ B_ M_

A A_ F_ W_

D_ O_ S_

D_ N_ S_

B_ B_ F_ S_

M_ O_

M_

I_ L_ O_

E_ E_

A_ M_

G_ O_ 30

---

Hint 1

> Numbers

Comment: Does the missing letters make another movie title?

Comment: @TroyAndAbed Something Relevant.

Comment: 5- Could be "Four Weddings and a Funeral"

Comment: @TroyAndAbed That is correct.

Comment: I didn't get them all, but you've already accepted the answer.

Comment: Perhaps for the sake of completeness, you can give me clues on the ones I couldn't crack?

Comment: @CodeNewbie Zero D_ T_, One Flew _, Three Men _, 11-11-11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Based on the previous hint (Movies) and the current hint (Numbers), the theme to this set is movies that contain some number in their titles...*

D_ T_

> Zero Dark Thirty

C_ F_ N_ T_ O_*

> One Flew Over The Cuckoo's Nest

N_ W_

> Two Weeks Notice

A A_ F_ W_  (Credit to TroyAndAbed)

> Four Weddings And A Funeral

A A_ B_ M_

> 3 Men And A Baby

D_ O_ S_

> 500 Days Of Summer / Six Degrees Of Separation

D_ N_ S_

> Six Days, Seven Nights

B_ B_ F_ S_

> Seven Brides For Seven Brothers

M_ O_

> One Man Jury

M_

> 12 Monkeys / 8 Mile

I_ L_ O_

> 10 Items Or Less

E_ E_

> 11-11-11

A_ M_

> 12 Angry Men

G_ O_ 30

> 13 Going On 30